# SQL query to find most active users by how many questions answered

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a score table that holds all questions answered on the site but it doesn't have the user_id who answered it. The score table has an attempt_id field which is a foreign key in a processed questions table that does have the user_id. So I want to join the tables with attempt_id and have a query which will select user_id and the count of questions answered by them and limit the top five users. The selected answer holds null if the question was loaded but not answered so for the query I am looking for the selected answer should not be null also.

Score Table
score_id **attempt_id** correct_answer selected_answer ...

Processed Questions Table
**attempt_id** user_id question_id

**Edit:** (Copied from OP's comment below:)

I can get the count of questions answered by a specific user using.

```
SELECT count(*)
from score a
   join ProcessedQuestion b on a.attempt_id = b.attempt_id
where user_id = [userID here] 
  and a.selected_answer is not null
```

but I have difficulty with doing it for multiple users

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not meant to create the answer for you, but to help you learn

Comment: i can get the count of questions answered by a specific user using. SELECT count(*) from score a join ProcessedQuestion b on a.attempt_id = b.attempt_id where user_id = [userID here] and a.selected_answer is not null but I have difficulty with doing it for multiple users

Comment: Do a GROUP BY to find each user's number of answers.

Comment: thanks group by is what I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, that gives you everything for a single user.

If you want to count the total amount of answers for all users, you can do something like the following:

`SELECT user_id, count(1) from score a join ProcessedQuestion b on a.attempt_id = b.attempt_id GROUP BY user_id`

Only showing the top 5 can be achieved by sorting the results, and adding a `LIMIT`clause.

`SELECT user_id, count(1) as Answers from score a join ProcessedQuestion b on a.attempt_id = b.attempt_id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count(1) DESC LIMIT BY 5`

Note that this is pseudo code, and not actually tested.

Comment: Note that `LIMIT` doesn't take ties into consideration.